# Rolling my own tobacco at office

Tags: employer-relations, unprofessional-behavior, brazil

I would like to know what do you guys think about rolling tobacco at work.

Background: I work in a office in São Paulo - Brazil. People here in Brazil do not have the habit to roll their own tobacco. Facing this fact often I hear jokes (maybe sarcastic jokes) like "Hey, are you smoking marijuana here at work?". So I have to explain everytime that is only tobacco.

People that smoke cigarette are actually discriminated and weed-smokers are very discriminated.

Is it a bad manner to roll tobacco at work in Brazil? It was completely natural for me, in Germany.

TWDM answer's gave me a little bit of concern. So I saw the HR office-chief passing by just me now. I called her privately and asked about it. She said - No worries, they are just joking up to you.

I guess my question can be closed but I think this discussion may be useful for a good discussion considering other places around the world. And it can be just her thoughts once every person has it's own opinion.

**EDIT**

TWDM answer's gave me a little bit of concern. So I saw the HR office-chief passing by just me now. I called her privately and asked about it. She said - No worries, they are just joking up to you.

Comment: As HR about your company's procedure (or about local laws), company specific (or legal) so off topic, voting to close.

Comment: Sounds like you already know the answer to your question. As TWDM said, this is fine in some locations and companies and frowned upon in others. Evidently it's not typical in your office and it may affect you negatively, especially if people associate it with drug use. The real question: why don't you just pre-roll your cigarettes at home?

Comment: I do not take cigarettes at home to prevent over-smoking. I like to roll my cigarette just in time as a way to clean my mind and do a little stop.

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager I am pretty sure this is not forbbiden and probably they have no laws/advices about this subject. Is just a matter of behaviour at work's place.
My question is based in the culture of Brazil or other similar places.

Comment: I'm assuming that you can't smoke in the office. Is there a reason you don't roll them outside the office as well?

Comment: @DavidK the only reason is to prevent take all the stuff outside office and go smoke.

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager I disagree, this question is most definitely not about company policy. The OP specifically asked about what is polite and customary in Brazil, not about what is allowed at his company.

Comment: Glad to hear that you resolved this Victor. Keep in mind that StackExchange is not a forum for discussion but a place to ask and answer questions that have practical answers. That's why this is getting close votes: everyone's opinion will be different and it will differ by company whether rolling a cigarette is accepted. As a crude example: it could be wildly inappropriate in a cancer-related non-profit but standard fare in a tobacco company.

Comment: @Lilienthal Thank you for the de advice. I am new here and maybe lacking some common behaviour at this community. Thank you for your politiness. Have a nice day.

Comment: You're quite welcome. Consider joining [chat] if you have further questions.

Comment: I don't think you need the "This question can be closed" in the question. Just leave the question here for people to read and learn from.

Comment: It's just the novelty of seeing someone rolling up, nothing to worry about, they'll all get used to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Disclaimer: I am not familiar with Brazilian culture, but the reactions you are getting from your coworkers seem similar to those I would see in America.**

I almost never see anyone roll their own tobacco, so seeing it at the workplace would be especially strange. It may not necessarily be impolite, but it is certainly out of the ordinary, and by doing so you draw attention to yourself. Hopefully after a while people will get used to it and the comments will go away. However, if you really don't like the remarks you are getting, then I suggest either rolling your tobacco at home or outside.

Comment: Since I started to do this 1 month ago, the reactions are getting low. I hope someone bad intentioned do not use this against me when I do something not right at my working procedures. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you need to practice rolling tobacco until it becomes second nature and "invisible". When I see people do this, they've typically been doing it for years and it takes so little time as to not even be noticeable.